# Why mysql tranmit date in year/month/day/hours/miniutes/seconds/nanos instead of unix timestamp?

Tags: mysql

Recently I ran into a timezone problem causing by the inconsistency of the client timezone and MySQL server time zone. After reading and debugging `mysql-connector` I pinned down the cause. But I am curious why MySQL transmit date in year/month/day/hours/minutes/seconds/Nanos as in `com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.MysqlBinaryValueDecoder#decodeTimestamp`. This behavior forces `mysql-connector` to be aware of server timezone and apparently use more bandwidth.

If this was for compatibility, why not just add a flag like `useLegacyDatetimeCode`?

Comment: Unix timestamp doesn’t allow subsecond accuracy, or times before 1970 for some reasons. Also I’m sure even with MySQL you can handle timezones properly, or use UTC for everything.

Comment: Subsecond accuracy is easy to achieve with unix timestamp, and the range for mysql timestamp is '1970-01-01 00:00:01.000000' to '2038-01-19 03:14:07.999999'. I know I can handle timezone properly with some configuration. I am just curious what's the benefit of not using unix timestamp.